# AWS CDK How to handle Fn.getAtt to return integer

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am utilizing a custom resource to retrieve an integer value. However, despite the CDK parameter specifically requiring an integer, I encounter an error stating `type of argument must be one of (int, float); got str instead`. Is there a method within CDK to ensure that the value is received as an integer, thereby avoiding this type mismatch error?

Comment: Custom resources only support str props, convert to int within the handler. Or if you are referring to an output att of the CR, use the helper cast methods on the Token class

Comment: @gshpychka any hint how to do it? the CR returns `response = {'statusCode': 200,'body': json.dumps({'value': 1236259})}`

Comment: `Token.asNumber` on the CDK side when you do `getAtt` (`Token.asNumber(Fn.getAtt(...))`)